# Why do I see same class twice in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jersey, embedded-jetty

I see two entries for same class in eclipse inside the jar: jersey-container-jetty-http.jar.

I suppose this is something to do with the fact that these classes are stub. How does it really work? Following classes have duplicate entries

1. JettyHttpContainer.class
2. JettyHttpContainerFactory.class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered a visual bug in your eclipse ide.

The jar itself does not contain duplicate classes.

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-jetty-http/3.0.2/jar

You should file a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT

Comment: I suspect there is more to it. The classes in question are those which have two implementations one for Java8 and another for java >11 and during build, appropriate classes is packaged into jar.

Comment: Nope.  You can download the jar and see that for yourself with the `jar -tvf <file.jar>` tool.  There's no JEP-238 MutliRelease JAR behaviors present in that jar.